# How to type function to accept only parameter types that are mapped to some other particular types?

Tags: typescript

I am writing a function that checks if field is required by passing field name as an argument. I want function to accept only those field names that are mapped in Config type to ValidationConfig which has required property. I know I can set function parameter type as ValidationField as per below and it works.

```
type Field = 'name' | 'surname' | 'age' | 'height' | 'school';

type ValidationField = Extract<Field, 'name' | 'surname'>;
type RequiredConfig = {required?: boolean};
type ValidationConfig<T> = T extends ValidationField ? RequiredConfig : {};

type Config = {
    [K in Field]?: ValidationConfig<K> & {visible?: boolean};
}

const config: Config = {name: {required: true, visible: true}, surname: {required: true, visible: true}, age: {visible: false}}

const checkRequired = (field: ValidationField) => config[field]?.required
```

However I would like to know if there is a way to achieve same behavior if we do not have access to ValidationField type, only to Config, Validation config and RequiredConfig types?

```
const checkRequired = <T extends Field>(field: Config[Field] extends ...? T : never) => config[field]?.required
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wRebLW) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, I was looking for solution with current types. I don't want to put all key value pairs in Config type as Field type will grow and Validation field will change accordingly, but as I said I have no control over those types. Is it even possible with current setup?

Comment: If you take my `type ValidationField =` line and drop it into your code (maybe rename the type if you still have the original one in scope somehow) then it will still work. I’ll show you when I get to a real computer.

Comment: Like, if you do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLOd4N), it is exactly the same. Does this meet your needs? I can write up an answer unless you still think I'm missing something.

Comment: @jcalz, that worked. As always you did a great job, sir. Thank you so much. Please write an answer so I can pick it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to inspect `Config` to re-create `ValidationField`, it looks like you should get just those property names where the value is assignable to `RequiredConfig | undefined` (where the `undefined` is there since [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) always include `undefined` as a possibility when you read from them):

```
type MyValidationField = { [K in keyof Config]-?:
    Config[K] extends RequiredConfig | undefined ? K : never
}[keyof Config]
//   ^? type MyValidationField = "name" | "surname"
```

This is a *distributive object type* where we [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the keys of `Config` (using the `-?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers)) to remove weirdness around optional properties) and check whether the property of `Config` is a `RequiredConfig` or not. If so, we put the key name as the property, otherwise we put `never`.  Then we [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the mapped type with `keyof Config` to get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of key names we care about.

You can see that this is `"name" | "surname"`, the same as `ValidationField`.  And then your `checkRequired()` function still works with `MyValidationField` instead of `ValidationField`:

```
const checkRequired = (field: MyValidationField) => config[field]?.required
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)